# Airflow Worker: Timed out waiting for UP message from <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, bash, airflow, celery

What is the cause of the below error in an Airflow worker? (Specifically AWS Managed Airflow if that makes a difference). Based on other answers, it seems to be related to child processes taking too long to initialize but I'm not sure where to look further with that. It's happening very often, not just occasionally and we're also seeing spikes in CPU Utilization on the workers so this may be related:

```
[2023-10-03 18:05:25,804: ERROR/MainProcess] Timed out waiting for UP message from <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
[2023-10-03 18:05:25,810: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-2' pid:74 exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'
```

Other than installing from requirements.txt, what could be causing the initialization to take a long time? Could it be just the requirements.txt if a couple of packages are being installed? How much time are the processes given to initialize? Could it be because there are many processes being initialized at once or is that unrelated? Many of our tasks are scheduled to start at the exact same time and that's the time we're seeing the CPUUtilization spike.

And is there some configuration option or change that can be done to prevent this error with child processes taking too long to initialize?

I'm also ocassionally seeing the error:

```
Task handler raised error: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 15 (SIGTERM) Job: 24.')
```

This seems to be related to to much memory consumption, is that correct? Are the two errors related at all? The tasks are using at most 7mb of storage in /tmp/ and less than 70mb between all of them. That doesn't seem like too much memory in general but is there a limit to how much can be placed in /tmp/? Is it too much given that the Medium environment class in Airflow has 4GB of RAM?